# aws cdk: build docker image with a base from another account

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

Have the following  to build a docker image in a CDK run

```
    const uploadImageAsset = new DockerImageAsset(this, 'UploaderImage', {
      directory: '../docker',
      platform: Platform.LINUX_AMD64,
      file: 'Dockerfile',
    });
```

The issue is my `FROM` in the `Dockerfile` is in a different account. The other account ECR permissions gives permissions for the account to pull. I just can't run the proper auth to get it to build

```
FROM 11112222233334444.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app:base-2021
```

Error i'm getting is

```
#3 [internal] load metadata for 11112222233334444.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app:base-2021



#3 ERROR: pulling from host 11112222233334444.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com failed with status code [manifests base-2021]: 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: The local credentials you have active when running `cdk synth` have to have the proper IAM permissions - do they?

Comment: What is the full policy statement (with account numbers redacted) that you have in your account that holds the image?

Comment: also see if something here helps https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17268

Answer (score 0):

You haven't exactly left a lot of information. But like Sachin Gupta already mentioned, check the IAM Permissions, the Policy related to the user you use must grant the actions for the specific repository.

As I interpret it, you already granted the resource policy.

Let us know what the problem was.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

issue may lie with IAM permissions - can u share what actions u have currently ?

1. Check on IAM permissions: Does the policy grants ecr:GetAuthorizationToken and ecr:BatchGetImage actions for the specific repository.
2. Cross-account access :  creating a cross-account resource policy may help if u dont have it already . https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cross-account-amazon-ecr-access-for-aws-lambda/